# How do I use Rack::Proxy within Rails to proxy requests to a specific path to another app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, proxy, rack, reverse-proxy, routes

I found this great [blog post](http://livsey.org/blog/2012/02/23/using-rack-proxy-to-serve-multiple-rails-apps-from-the-same-domain-and-port/) on how to use `Rack::Proxy` as a separate proxy app. The article explains how he uses `Rack::Proxy` to proxy requests to `http://localhost:3000` to an app on port `3001` and requests to `http://localhost:3000/api` to an app on port `3002`. I want to do the same thing, but I do not want to create a separate proxy app. Instead, I want my main Rails app to proxy requests to `/blog` to a different app.

Blog Post: http://livsey.org/blog/2012/02/23/using-rack-proxy-to-serve-multiple-rails-apps-from-the-same-domain-and-port/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

##### **lib/proxy.rb**

```
require 'rack-proxy'
class Proxy < Rack::Proxy
    def initialize(app)
        @app = app
    end

    def rewrite_env(env)
        # do magic in here
    end
end
```

##### **config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.use "Proxy"
```

Comment: would have been nice to see what exactly the "magic" was that you were talking about

Comment: you can put Proxy.rb in app/middleware in Rails 4

Answer (score 32):

FWIW, I also just tackled this problem. Some may find the full code helpful, as I needed more than you posted:

```
# lib/proxy_to_other.rb
class ProxyToOther < Rack::Proxy
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    original_host = env["HTTP_HOST"]
    rewrite_env(env)
    if env["HTTP_HOST"] != original_host
      perform_request(env)
    else
      # just regular
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

  def rewrite_env(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if request.path =~ %r{^/prefix|^/other_prefix}
      # do nothing
    else
      env["HTTP_HOST"] = "localhost:3000"
    end
    env
  end
end
```

Also:

```
# config/application.rb
# ...snip ...
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Custom Rack middlewares
    config.middleware.use "ProxyToOther" if ["development", "test"].include? Rails.env
#...snip....
```

This assumes your app you want to proxy some requests to is running on port 3001. I daresay the app you're hitting can be run on any port. This also assumes you only want to do the proxying in development and test environments, because you'll have a 'real' solution in production & staging (eg, nginx or a loadbalancer doing the proper thing).

Comment: This is great.  If you want to proxy to an arbitrary app on the internet, you may also have to set `env["SERVER_PORT"] = 80`

Comment: " This also assumes you only want to do the proxying in development and test environments, because you'll have a 'real' solution in production & staging (eg, nginx or a loadbalancer doing the proper thing)." - Why is that? Shouldn't I use Rack::Proxy in production?

Comment: @DavidLojudiceSobrinho you certainly could, but it would be better to do that proxying with nginx/apache or a loadbalancer. You'll be using up a thread in your app to do a synchronous HTTP request to some other server. It's just not a wise use of resources.

Comment: Great answer, @steve. Sorry for not putting any detail into my original answer. It has been some now since I encountered that problem and I don't even have the code base for it anymore. Looks like wbyoung also has a good answer, so to save an argument, I'll give you guys both an upvote.

Comment: How do I write a test for this in Rspec?

Comment: @YoniBaciu if you wanted to write a unit spec, you would instantiate an instance of this and call its methods and then make assertions. Assuming you're using webmock, you could assert that a request to your other service was made.

Answer (score 17):

This is a slight change to steve's solution that uses a little less internal understanding of `Rack::Proxy`:

```
require 'rack/proxy'

class MyProxy < Rack::Proxy
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    # call super if we want to proxy, otherwise just handle regularly via call
    (proxy?(env) && super) || @app.call(env)
  end

  def proxy?(env)
    # do not alter env here, but return true if you want to proxy for this request.
    return true
  end

  def rewrite_env(env)
    # change the env here
    env["HTTP_HOST"] = "some.other.host"
    env
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is even simpler code to proxy an api when you want http://localhost:3000/api/users/1 (for example) to go to the api namespace defined in routes.rb without using a proxy server program.

On production it would be something like http://api.sample.com/users/1.

**lib/proxy.rb**

```
require 'rack-proxy'

class Proxy < Rack::Proxy
   def perform_request(env)
     request = Rack::Request.new(env)
     if request.path =~ %r{^/api}
       #do nothing
     else
       @app.call(env)
     end
   end
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.use "Proxy"
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json },
        constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
  resources :users, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
end
```

**lib/api_constraints.rb**

```
class ApiConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.sample.v#{@version}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found gem **[rails-reverse-proxy](https://github.com/axsuul/rails-reverse-proxy)** more simpler and obvious to use (for react app):

Add a simple proxy controller:

```rb
class ProxyController < ApplicationController
  include ReverseProxy::Controller

  def index
    reverse_proxy "http://localhost:3000" do |config|
      # We got a 404!
      config.on_missing do |code, response|
        redirect_to root_url and return
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And add a route:

```rb
match 'static/*path' => 'proxy#index', via: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete]
```